# How to serialize and deserialize a RenderedImage as a text string?

Tags: java, string, image, serialization

I want to serialize a RenderImage as a text string so that I can java a Jason-like file with some fields (Name, Date, Photo).

I would like to use

```
String s = String.format("%s:%s,%s:%s,%:%s", 
"name", my_name, 
"date", date, 
"photo", someFunctionToGenerateAStringForTheImage(RenderedImage));
```

And save s to a file.

Currently, I am using this:

```
public static byte[] imageToByteArray(RenderedImage img) {
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", out);
        out.flush();
        return out.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

And I call it as such:

```
String imageAsString =new String(Util.imageToByteArray(post.getImage()));
```

I deserialize the strings using the following function:

```
public static RenderedImage byteArrayToImage(byte[] bytes) {
    try (ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)) {
        return ImageIO.read(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Thus I call it as such byteArrayToImage(imageAsString.getBytes());

Unfortunately, this approach is not working, the objects produced aren't the same... I would like to it using a String.format because my code is much more complex and full of recursive calls, so I want the simplest way of achieving this.

What can you recommend me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [Data URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
public static String imageToDataUrl(RenderedImage img) { 
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        ImageIO.write(img, "png", bytes);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    String data = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(bytes.toByteArray()),
    //proper data url format
    dataUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + data;

    return dataUrl;
}
```

And to deserialise:

```
public static RenderedImage dataUrlToImage(String dataUrl) {
    String data = dataUrl.substring(dataUrl.indexOf(',')+1);        
    byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(data);

    try (ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes)) {
        return ImageIO.read(in);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create class

```
class MyImage {
  String name;
  Date date;
  String photo;
}
```

and use any json lib, for example GSON:

```
String s = new GSON.toJson(myImage).replace('{'}.replace{'}');
MyImage myImage = new GSON.fromJson("{"+s+"}", MyImage.class);
```

**Update**: 
if you have problem with serialization image try to use:

```
String s = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF8");
byte[] utf8Bytes = original.getBytes("UTF8");
```

instead of 
   String s = new String(utf8Bytes);
   byte[] defaultBytes = original.getBytes();

Comment: The problem is that I cannot serialize the image itself. I save it to a file, but when reading it back the image is not the same as the original (this is an actual image file).

Comment: Fixed my post, try to use one codding page